# CDS Entity connect and edit from MS Access

Tags: powerapps

I am wondering if it is possible to create a linked table from MS Access to Power Apps CDS Entity table and to update and modify data. I can do it via Excel, but I cannot find any info, if I can do the same with MS Access.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use ODBC driver that I created with this tool "https://www.cdata.com/drivers/microsoftcds/odbc/" - then I was able to create two-way sync with Access